# Using computed upper index in firebird to compare case insensitive strings

Tags: sql, indexing, firebird

DB: firebird 2.5.4

I have 1 table, 2 string fields and 1 computed field:

```
Files
 name varchar 256
 extension varchar 4
 filename computed by name||extension
```

I want to search a filename in this table (case insensisive)

The query is

```
Select * 
from files f
where upper(f.filename) = upper('test.txt')
```

This is working of course, and to speed up the query, I created a computed index on files on `upper(filename)`

```
CREATE INDEX test ON FILES COMPUTED BY (upper(filename));
```

Now, the same query doesn't work anymore ! It returns nothing.
I tried an index on lower, but it doesn't work either.

wtf? Did I miss an option somewhere?

Comment: At first glance it sounds like a bug, I will see if I can reproduce (tonight, don't have access to a Firebird instance right now)

Comment: I edited the post with more complete description 2 min ago.

Comment: There was a post on the firebird-support mailinglist last week where someone mentioned a similar problem with indexes on computed columns. As a workaround you could probably make `filename` a normal column and populate it in a trigger on update and insert.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it, but in my case it works. What is the ODS and dialect of the database?

Comment: And could you also share the actual DDL of the table and the default character set of the database?

Comment: @Mark, I tried to build a sample from my db with a single table, and I can't. It seems that when I re-create the index, it works as expected ?! It was created with a previous version. I think I will extract all metadatas and rebuild all my db...

Comment: A backup and restore should be sufficient as that will recreate the indexes. You might have been bitten by the index problem described in the release notes: http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes254.html#notes-253

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Thank you the info and sorry for bad report. I will update the answer with the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems firebird doesn't support computed indexes on computed fields.
I replaced the computed field 'filename' with the regular fields 'name||extension' in index. It fixes the problem:

```
CREATE INDEX test ON FILES COMPUTED BY (upper(name||extension));
```

Bug report found [here](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1212).

[EDIT]

After trying to spot the problem, it appears my database has internal errors, due to the migration from an earlier version. Mark Rotteveel points me to the release notes where the problem is described:

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes254.html#notes-253

I extracted the metadata and rebuild the whole database. This fixes the problem.
Note that a backup and restore should work as well.

Thank you Mark.

Comment: It's not  a bug.  It is a feature request.  :-)  I personally would not have expected an index on a non-stored column.

Comment: See the edited part of the message for the solution. Indexes on non-stored columns work very well.